Does every sequence of points have a point that is arbitrarily close infinitely often?
Suppose we have some compact set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and some sequence $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $x_i\in X$ for all $i$.
Let $(d_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be some positive non-increasing sequence with $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}d_i=0$.
Is there always some point $x^{*}\in X$ such that $|x^{*}-x_i|_1\leq d_i$ for infinitely many $i$?

For some background, this question arose as I was trying to extend a proof from a finite to an infinite case. If $X$ is finite this clearly holds, as in fact there must even be one $x\in X$ that appears infinitely often in the sequence itself.
For infinite $X$ this is no longer the case, but for some fixed $d$, we must be $d$-close to some point infinitely often since we can again find a finite subset $Y\subset X$ that 'covers' $X$ in the sense that every $x\in X$ is $d$-close to some $y\in Y$. Geometrically, we are saying there is a finite number of $L^1$ balls with radius $d$ that cover $X$, and $Y$ is the collection of midpoints of these balls. Then again at least one of the finitely many balls must be hit infinitely often by the sequence.
In the question the geometric interpretation the balls decrease in size over time, meaning the argument no longer works. I do not really have an intuition for whether this holds or not since on one hand all for all $d_i$ there is such a covering of $L^1$-balls, but on the other hand of course there is no finite set $Y$ such that $X$ is covered for all $d_i$.

I tried using the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the $L^1$-distance is a metric space and thus sequentially compact, i.e. there is a subsequence $(x_{j_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where the limit is well defined, i.e. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{j_n}=x\in X$. However, I am not sure where to continue here since it seems I'd also need to show that somehow the subsequence $(x_{j_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges 'faster' towards $x$ than $d_i$ converges towards $0$.
I think this already shows that for a given sequence $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ we can find a point $x^{*}$ and sequence $(d_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that the condition holds, but it is not sufficient when $(d_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is also given, correct?

Is $n$ finite?  If not, there are very easy counterexamples, e.g., let $x_i$ be the $0$ vector, except it's $i^{\text{th}}$ component is $1$.  Is $\sum_i d_i^n$ infinite?  If not, there are very easy counterexamples, e.g., if the $\sum_i d_i^n$ is sufficiently small compared to the measure of $X$, the collection ${B_{d_i}(x_i)}$ can be disjointly scattered around $X$ or be a packing by tangent balls.

Here's an easy counterexample.
Take $X = [0,1]$ and the sequence $x_n = 1/n$.  Let $d_n = 1/(2 n)$.  For every $x^* \ne 0$, take $N$ so $x^* > 3/(2N)$, then for $n > N$,
$|x^* - 1/n| \ge x^* - 1/n > 1/(2n)$.  On the other hand, for $x^* = 0$ we have $|x^* - 1/n| = 1/n > 1/(2n)$ for all $n$.
[EDIT] It's easy to find counterexamples where the sequence converges, or has a finite number of limit points.  But you may be interested to know that the answer is "yes" if the sequence $x_n$ is dense in $X$.
This is because for any sequence $d_n > 0$, $U_N = \bigcup_{n > N} B_{d_n}(x_n)$ (where $B_r(x)$ is the open ball in $X$ of radius $r$ centred at $x$) is a dense open set in $X$, and by the Baire Category Theorem
$\bigcap_N U_N$ is dense in $X$.

If the sequences $(x_i)$ and $(d_i)$ are given, then this is not true in general.  Suppose $d_i=\frac{1}{2^{i+1}}$ and $x_i=(\frac{1}{2^i},0,0,\ldots,0)$.  Since the points $x_i$ converge to the origin, the only possible $x^*$ is the origin, $(0,0,\ldots,0)$.  However, for this point: $|x^* - x_i|=\frac{1}{2^i} = 2d_i$.  If you were able to re-order the $x_i$, then it would be true.
